# Application specific routing in windows

Tags: windows, networking, routing

Would it be possible to make a specific application to use a specific route to access the internet?

Well this is my scenario:
 my laptop is connected to two gateways one with ip address 10.10.10.1 and the other one with IP address 192.168.1.1[image: A part of my routing table]

I want to send all my traffic through 10.10.10.1 except for FireFox which I want it to use 192.168.1.1 to connect to the internet...
is there a way to do this?

P.S. what I am thinking is using something like a proxy to send firefox's traffic to the other route but I don't know how

Comment: This should be possible with `netsh interface portproxy` but I'm wondering why would you like to do so?
Is there a fixed range of addresses you're gonna access through 10.10.10.1? You could set a route for that which is easier to maintain.

Comment: they are actually two DSL modems connected to two different ISPs. One of the ISP's don't allow torrenting but has a good speed for browsing so there is no specific destination I could use to add a static route